# How to refresh grid after ajax call in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

HI,
I have a asp.net mvc grid with delete and edit button. when i click on delete button i need to delete the data and refresh the grid. for this i am making an ajax call which deletes the data, but not ablet o refresh the grid.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you say grid is this just a basic table that you've added delete and edit button to, or is it a grid control by someone?

If it's just a table then what you probably need to do is remove the row you've deleted using javascript (which will be made much easier with something like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove#expr)).

Another approach would be to use something like [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) which handles a lot of that for you. Although it can take a little while to get up and running, in my experience it's normally worthwhile.

Comment: +1 manipulate the dom using jQuery to acheive the result when some element is deleted/updated .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a callback for the Ajax helpers in MVC "OnSuccess", you could remove the row using this callback, The success callback, as well as any other callbacks you can specify in the AjaxOptions object, receives only one argument of type AjaxContext. 
Heres a breakdown of the callback function javascript object properties.

example callback

```
function OnSuccess(context){
... do stuff here
}
```

**get_data**
 Gets any data returned from the controller action.

**get_insertionMode**
 Indicates how to treat the response (only if markup), whether to replace, prepend, or append it to the markup of the specified DOM element. The default is replace.

**get_loadingElement**
 Indicates the DOM element to be displayed to indicate that an AJAX call is going on.

**get_request**
 Gets the Sys.Net.WebRequest object that represents the current request.

**get_response**
 Gets the Sys.Net.WebRequestExecutor object for the current request.

**get_updateTarget**
 Indicates the DOM element to be automatically updated with the returned markup, if any.

This should be everything you need inorder to perform your edit/delete.

Comment: @ori: thanks for your sugestion, but i tried to uise the jquery, but getting error for jquery grid ERROR: "object not supported". Can u please tell me what is the cause for this?

Comment: How are you using jquery?? could you provide some code above in your question.